# RICH:dataTable - add new row

Tags: jsf, richfaces

how can I add new row to extendedDataTable at the end of the list? Is there some solution?

JSF table example:

[image]

Can you help me?

**UPDATE**:

I'm able to add new item using for example a rich:popupPanel, but not by creating a new row in datatable. What I wanted to say, I'm able to save but not as elegant as using [BalusCs JSF guide](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2006/06/using-datatables.html#AddNewRowsToDatatable).

**Part of XHTML:**

```
<rich:extendedDataTable 
 id="tableDetail"
 value="#{myBdeCheck.dataListBde}"
 var="bdeItem">

<rich:column width="80px">
  <f:facet name="header">
     <h:outputText value="Směna" />
  </f:facet>
  <h:outputText value="#{bdeItem.dayShift}"/>
</rich:column>

<rich:column width="70px">
  <f:facet name="header">
     <h:outputText value="Karta" />
  </f:facet>
  <h:outputText value="#{bdeItem.bdeno}"/>
</rich:column>
```

**Part of BEAN:** 
package common;

```
@ViewScoped
@ManagedBean(name="myBdeCheck")
public class MyBdeCheck extends Tools
{
  /**/
  private static final long serialVersionUID = -6586004426692130933L;

  private Session session; 
  private List<BDE> dataListBde; //= new ArrayList<BDE>();
  private int currentIndexDetail;   // index for BDEDetail datatable

  private BDECheckView editedWork;  // one item of BdeCheckView
  private BDE BDEItem;              // one item of BdeData

  // Constructor 
  public MyBdeCheck()
  {
    editedWork = new BDECheckView();
    BDEItem = new BDE();
  }

  /** GET DATA FROM BDEData *******************
   * @param personalNum, dayShift [whole day: YYYY-MM-DD%]
   */
  private void criteriaCheck()
  {
    try 
    {
      Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(BDE.class);
      {some restrictions}
      dataListBde = criteria.list();
    }  
    catch (Exception e) {...}
   }

  public void saveBde()
  {    
    try
    {
      DaoCrud.update(dataListBde, 'R');  // ulozeni do dtb
    }
    catch  {...}  
  }

  public void saveNew() {...}

// and GETTERS AND SETTERS 
}
```

Comment: what version of richfaces/jsf?

Comment: can you just add a new element to the collection backing the dataTable and then reRender the component?

Comment: (i've edited my post) I'm only add new Item and reRender dataTable, but not using collection

Comment: any chance you could post the xhtml and backing bean so we can see how it's working now? I think it would be easier to see what you are trying to accomplish that way.

Comment: OK. So your list IS backed by a collection: private List<BDE> dataListBde;. So if you add a new BDE() to that collection and rerender the datatable your new row will show up. Then you can just save the collection to persist it. what am i missing?

Comment: Ehm, I'm idiot (I mean very tired), you're right :] And how can I tell dataTable that the new row will be editable (inputtext)?

Comment: i've added the answer below along with a summary of what we discussed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your dataTable is modeling a Collection:

```
private List<BDE> dataListBde;
```

To add a new row you would just need to add a new BDE() to the Collection.

```
this.dataListBde.add(new BDE());
```

Then you can just reRender your dataTable to see the new row.

Finally, in your xhtml you can conditionally render an inputText or outputText:

```
<rich:column width="70px">
    <f:facet name="header">
        <h:outputText value="Karta" />
    </f:facet>
    <h:outputText value="#{bdeItem.bdeno}" rendered="#{bdeItem.bdeno != null}"/>
    <h:inputText value="#{bdeItem.bdeno}" rendered="#{bdeItem.bdeno == null}"/>
</rich:column>
```

Comment: Nice and simple. Thank you very much, Dave! :-)

Answer (score 3):

The general jsf approach would be to add an empty element at the end of the underlying list in the backing bean and then in your dataTable render an `h:outputText` if the row element contains data and an `h:inputText` or some other input component if the row element is empty.

See [BalusC's blog entry on "Using datatables"](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2006/06/using-datatables.html#AddNewRowsToDatatable) for an example.

It shouldn't be a big problem to adapt it to Richfaces.

Comment: Thank you, I'll try to adapt it. My JSF tables are made using BalusC guide. But I thought rich:dataTable could have such a feature included...