# Add a row to rich:datatable manually for input text

Tags: jsf, richfaces

I want to add a row at the end of my rich:datatable that shows information
and in this row I want to put some input that enable user to add new data 
I read this answer :
[RICH:dataTable - add new row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6041540/richdatatable-add-new-row)
but for me is a little different
I don't have any list

my xhtml is like this :

```
<rich:dataTable value="#{serverMB.allServer}" var="servers1" iterationStatusVar="it"  id="table" rows="15"
            style="direction: rtl ; text-align: right">
<rich:column>
    <f:facet name="header">#</f:facet>
    #{it.index+1}
</rich:column>
<f:facet name="header">
    <h:outputText value="#{msgs.servers}"/>
</f:facet>
<rich:column filterValue="#{serverMB.serverNameFilter}"
             filterExpression="#{fn:containsIgnoreCase(servers1.server_name,serverMB.serverNameFilter )}">
    <f:facet name="header">
        <h:outputText value="#{msgs.server_name}"/>
        <h:inputText value="#{serverMB.serverNameFilter}">
            <a4j:ajax event="blur" render="table" execute="@this"/>

        </h:inputText>
    </f:facet>
    <h:outputText value="#{servers1.server_name}"/>

</rich:column>
.
.
.
```

and my managedbean is like this

```
  public List<Server> getAllServer() {

    return serverFacade.findAll();
}
```

I use this method to show information so there is not any list that I personally can add a row to it and so on ...
so what I must do ?

Comment: `getAllServer` returns a List. There's your list

Comment: so where can I add a new row to it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Your serverList should be populated and set as a class-level variable. Use an `@PostConstruct` method to populate the list:

   ```
   @PostConstruct
   public void initServerList(){
     //declare serverList as a class-scoped variable in your managed bean 
     serverList = serverFacade.findAll();
   }
   ```
2. Declare a method in your managed bean that will add to the `serverList`

   ```
   public void incrementList(){

      Server server = new Server(); //create a dummy Server object
      serverList.add(server); // List has been incremented. Be sure to AJAX-refresh the datatable after calling this method to reflect the new row.
   }
   ```
3. Collect information from the JSF view which you'll then use to fill the fields of the dummy object:

   ```
   public void updateLatestServer(){

      Server lastServer = serverList.get(serverList.size-1);
      lastServer.setName(serverNameFromView);     
      lastServer.setIP(IPFromView); 
   }
   ```

   The `serverNameFromView` and `IPFromView` are hypothetical variables you'll collect in your JSF Form.

Comment: thanks for your complete answer , you are right ,so with out populating serverList I can't do the same thing ?

Comment: @omidhaghighatgoo I don't see how. Basic java: you need the same list to be available when adding a dummy object and when updating the dummy object. The design is up to you. My answer is just a recommendation